# Sum of digits in a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, integer, digits

This function is supposed to return the sum of all the digits in a number.

```
def sum_digits(num):
    if int(num) <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sum = 0
        while int(num) != 0:
            n = int(num) % 10
            num = int(num) / 10
            sum = int(sum + n)
        return sum
```

It works fine for smaller numbers, but if i enter for example number 999999999999999999999999999999999 it returns 74 instead of 297.

Thanks for help

Comment: How about `sum(int(i) for i in str(num))`?

Comment: If you step through your code you should quickly see what it does wrong.

Comment: ``/`` is regular division, aka floating point math – use ``//`` for floor division, aka integer math. ``float`` is not sufficient to hold 999999999999999999999999999999999 accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide with (//) instead of (/), because that would return a floating number.
You need to do something like this:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    num = int(num)
    if num <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sum = 0
        while num != 0:
            n = num % 10
            num //= 10
            sum +=  n
        return sum
```

(I reformated your code a little for better readability.)

edit: typo fixed

Answer (score -1):

I approached your problem a little different

```
number = 999999999999999999999999999999999
    number = str(number)
    sum = 0
    for digit in number:
        digit = int(digit)
        sum = digit+sum
    print(sum)
```

Comment: That doesn't explain what is the problem, though.

Comment: Please do not re-use names of builtins such as ``sum`` – especially not if they would concisely solve the problem.